# Unable to Assign Values to Combo Box from Database

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Forms Project, one of form in which em using a combo Box.
I have Hard code Collection of Combo Box.Scenario is that user open form, enter information and save it into the Database and also press enter key on specific text box then the values show that retrieve from data base.

At this form i have put "Enter key event" on specific Text Box,When i press Enter key it show value from database it works fine for text box not work for combo box.
it is not showing value that assign to combo box retrieve from database.Pleas Put Code Reference.

```
ComboBox1.item="some value"
```

Comment: It's difficult to see what's being asked here, can you make an edit to make your post as clear as possible?

Comment: Try `comboBox1.Text = "Some value"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no property called `item` on ComboBox. There is one called Items but it has no setter. You should have DisplayMember and ValueMember on your objects and set DataSource, alternatively, use `Items.Add("My option")`.

Example:

```
 string[] stringArray = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
 comboBox1.DataSource = stringArray;

          OR
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Number,Name from MyTable", conn);
 conn.Open();
 SqlDataAdapter DataA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataTable DSet = new DataTable();
 DataA.Fill(DSet);
 conn.Close();
 ComboBox1.DataSource = DSet;
 ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
 ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Number";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert item first into collection:

```
int index = Combobox1.Items.Add("some value");
Combobox1.SelectedIndex = index;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FindStringExact Methode ..

```
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = ComboBox1.FindStringExact("searchvalue")
```

Reference .. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c440x2eb.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1